# Setting system volume in macOS when an external display with speakers is connected

Tags: macos, keyboard, audio, sound-volume, speakers

Recently I purchased an external display for my MacBook Pro (2017). I chose an LG 27UK850. The display has built-in speakers and is connected to my MacBook via USB-C port.

The speakers are working fine, but I can't use the volume keys (+/-) on my keyboard any more. If I want to change the volume I have to use the buttons under the display.

[image]

Is there any way or a "hack" to enable volume control from my keyboard?

Comment: Some questions for you: (1) Does your MacBook Pro have a Touch Bar or physical keys? (2) What have you tried so far to rectify this? (3) Can you confirm you're wanting to use the built-in keyboard, as opposed to an external keyboard? (4) What options are selected in the Sound system preference pane? (5) Are you using the cable that shipped with the LG display, or another cable?